# How to replace clipper power cord

Tags: electrical, cord-and-plug

Have an old pair of barber clippers. They aren't particularly nice but they have a lot of sentimental value. The power cord has been fraying for a long time right where it connects to the clippers and it finally broke. I kind of spliced it back together and taped it up but it doesn't feel very reliable or safe. I opened it up and took a look inside and it looks pretty basic. If I can find a power cord with the right connectors and rubber stopper block, it seems like it would be pretty easy to fix. Any ideas where I can buy one?

##### Follow up question:

The power cord has two separate wires coming out of it. Does it matter which wire I connect to which screw inside the clipper? And if so, how would I know which goes where?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The power cord, most hardware stores will have replacements.  The rubber stopper might be hard, design differences.  If the cord is sealed/glued to the block, you might need to slice the block carefully to remove and replace the cord.

Answer (score 4):

You may be able to slide the rubber stopper block back along the cord, depending on construction (*i.e.* it may be slipped on, not molded in place)

Note that the **surface of the two wires** making the cord is **different** - one is smooth, the other has ridges. Maintain the connection of the ridged side and smooth side since that indicates polarization if the plug is polarized. If the plug is not polarized it does not really matter. This is the stock manner of indicating which wire is which in that sort of cordage.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to shorten the cord and remove the damaged part, but this cord is of an ancient style with twisted wires. These days power cord tend to have a bit more insulation than this, for safety, so it would be better to change it.

Reach into the junk bin, pull out a power cord like this:

[image]

...and cut the extra connector at the end.

If you need to buy one, it is likely it will be cheaper to buy an extender or this kind of cord and cut it, than but one without connector.

You will need the two crimp connectors at the end and a crimp tool.

Answer (score 0):

For the follow up question.  It does not matter to the clipper.

The usual convention is to connect the hot/live wire to the switch.  Modern plugs have different prongs, one wide(neutral) and one narrow(hot).  This is for North American plugs.

If the clippers are old enough, then both prongs are probably the same, so it will depend on which way(top/bottom) you plug in to which wire is hot.

An ohm meter can tell which wire goes to which prong before you connect the wire to the clipper.